# How to make your own UDP packet using C++?

Tags: c++, udp

I have a problem in getting the destination IP address and destination port number in C++.
How can I do that using C++?
If there is any language other than C++ which is best to make your own UDP/TCP packets, then please tell me.

Comment: You should look for a proper library to do this, rather than create your own code. Then, the only thing you need to do is call the right function(s). The language is not the problem here, it is knowledge of how to build a correct packet. This is already done and tested in the library functions.

Comment: Can you explain your question better? You are struggling with getting destination ip & port from a recvfrom? Or?